# Jquery ajax returning extra information

Tags: c#, web-services, jquery

I want to return a string from a jquery ajax request but its returning my string and also some other stuff. I think its asp webservice information.

Here's my jquery request

```
jQuery.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "../WebService.asmx/GetProductLink",
            data: 'productId=' + productId + '&companyId=' + companyId,
            contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

and here's what is returned on success

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">http://www.facebook.com/Soundworkz</string>
```

The part i want is the http://www.facebook.com/Soundwork part.

Thanks

Comment: any particuler reason you have set the datatype to `text`

Comment: Your web service returns an XML response even though you're telling jQuery to expect a text dataType.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dataType` as `xml` i.e

```
 dataType: "xml"
```

Or remove `dataType` option.

Answer (score 0):

remove this line

```
dataType: "text",
```

and let the jquery guess the correct dataType as returned by the server